# get ALL specified substring in powershell

Tags: regex, powershell

I am trying to get "SubString One" AND "SubString two"
the script I am using allows me to have the substring between  substring , but :

1) only the first one substring and not all of them
2) Does not support multilines, which means I won't have "SubString One" in the example above

Help Please !

```
$a = " randomText <style>SubString One
</style>
another randomText   <style>SubString two </style>"

$pattern = "<style>(.*?)</style>"

$b = [regex]::Match($a,$pattern).Groups[1].Value

write-host $b
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Since your first `<style>` element spans two lines, you must turn on the SingleLine regex option in order to make `.` also match newlines (line breaks).
- To find *multiple* matches in the input string, use the `::Matches()` rather than the `::Match()` method.

```
$a = " randomText <style>SubString One
</style>
another randomText   <style>SubString two </style>"

# Inline option (?s) (SingleLine) makes '.' match newlines.
$pattern = "(?s)<style>(.*?)</style>"

# Use ::Matches() and .ForEach() to extract the capture-group match
# from each match.
# .Trim() removes surrounding whitespace, notably the newline at the
# end of 'SubString One'
[regex]::Matches($a, $pattern).ForEach({ $_.Groups[1].Value.Trim() })
```

The above yields:

```
SubString One
SubString two
```